# Usage of dummy indices in a sum

Tags: calculus, index-notation

A current textbook I'm reading has the following example of how to take derivatives of summations
$$\frac{d}{dt}\sqrt{\sum_jA_jB_j} = \frac{\sum_k\dot{A}_kB_k + A_k\dot{B}_k}{2\sqrt{\sum_jA_jB_j}}$$
where the overdots indicate time derivatives.

Why do we need to change the dummy index from $j$ to $k$ on the numerator? Shouldn't it not matter since both $j$ and $k$ run from 1 to $n$?

Thank you.

Comment: Just a matter of taste.

Comment: Sure. It is more of a method to distinguish the summations. I would even have used parentheses in the numerator. Maybe it should prevent people from canceling any terms, but honestly, I guess the author didn't even think about it. $k$ is generally better to read than $j$ or even worse, $i$ and $l$. Hence: the numerator came in naturally, the denominator came from copy and paste.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $$
\frac{\sum_k \left( \dot{A}_kB_k + A_k\dot{B}_k\right)}{2\sqrt{\sum_jA_jB_j}}
=\frac{\sum_j \left( \dot{A}_jB_j + A_j\dot{B}_j\right)}{2\sqrt{\sum_jA_jB_j}}
=\frac{\sum_k \left( \dot{A}_kB_k + A_k\dot{B}_k\right)}{2\sqrt{\sum_kA_kB_k}}
=\frac{\sum_j \left( \dot{A}_jB_j + A_j\dot{B}_j\right)}{2\sqrt{\sum_kA_kB_k}}
$$

Comment: It's a good habit, which can also prevent having to change indexes midway e.g.  $\;\displaystyle \frac{\sum_k a_k}{\sum_j b_j} = \sum_k \frac{a_k}{\sum_j b_j}\;$ "flows" more naturally then $\;\displaystyle \frac{\sum_j a_j}{\sum_j b_j} = \sum_k \frac{a_k}{\sum_j b_j}\;$.